# CKEditor enter key press scrolls to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am working on a php project in which I am using a ckeditor. Everything else seems to work fine, other than when I press enter key I get scrolled to the bottom of the page. I tried the following code.

```
 CKEDITOR.replace( fieldId,
            {  
                height:heightVal,width:widthVal,
            toolbar: [
                { name: 'document',    items: [ 'Source' ] },
                { name: 'clipboard',   items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },    
                { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll' ] },
                { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic',  'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
                { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
                { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink'] },
                { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image',  'Table', 'Flash', 'Video'] },
                { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor' ] },
                { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles' ,'FontSize']},
                { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
            ],
            enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV
            } 

        );
```

This doesn't help. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: What happens when you just use: CKEDITOR.replace( fieldId );  ?  Does it still scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, it still scrolls to the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed such issue in my project by changing any CSS rule `height: 100%` to `height: auto` for parent elements of editing area. In my case it was `<html>`, so check whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You set the enter mode to using a div.

You could have some kind of style on divs height?

Can you test it by switching to

```
enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
```

Does this change the behaviour?

UPDATE : i found this: [fixed bug](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9136)
Maybe updating ckeditor could fix the problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add
if ( parent.is( 'body' ) )
{
 overflowed = false;
}

I did not understand what the solution is.

Comment: Just downloaded a ckeditor, but the file
CKEditor/trunk/_source/core/dom/element.js
seems not to be present. 

But the bug is marked to be triggered by an absolute container around the ckeditor or body at 100% height.
Do you have one of these style on your page?

Any way if they fixed the bug, the last version could just simply work. 
Or you maybe have already the last one?

Comment: I tried adding 
    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR

But still no use. Can you please pass me the link to download the new changes for ckeditor.

Comment: The ckeditor is within an iframe, if I open the iframe source directly then the enter key doesnt cause any problem. Only if I try it within the iframe it scrolls to the bottom of the iframe on enter key press.